# SQL query in hibernate to include subsets but exclude supersets

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities:

- `Games` (let it have objects `a`,`b`)
- `Tags`  (let it have objects `1`,`2`)

and a junction table `GameTags` which has a one-to-many relationship with both the entities (`Games` & `Tags`). This means if `a` is associated to `1` and `2` AND `b` is associated to `1`, then there will be three records in table `GameTags`.

#### Problem:

Given, I have a list of search tags (`ST`), I want to find all the games who's tags are either a subset of `ST` or equal to `ST`.

#### Naive approach:

A naive approach I have considered - execute all `2^n -1` SQL queries and for all the resulting games find all tags and compare with `ST` to exclude games which are not a subset of `ST`. However, I believe there has to be a better way to handle sets in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an exists subquery like this:

```
select g from Games g
where exists (
    select 1 
    from g.tags t
    where t.id in :tagIds
)
```